# ASP.Net, how to fix website size in different size screens

Tags: asp.net

how to fix the setting of website page in different screen sizes in ASP.NET.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No way, as ASP.NET is a *server side* scripting language -- and the server does not display any pages to a screen and has therefore no "screen size".

Answer (score 0):

Matten is correct, of course, that this question has nothing to do with ASP.NET - it's more an HTML/CSS question and not that hard to research.  However, here are some basics:

Generally, I put all or most of the page into a DIV with a certain width - anywhere from 50-90%, depending on what looks good. That takes care of the *width*.

After the header, the rest of my pages often need to scroll without losing the header, so that all goes in a DIV called "scrollcontainer", then I include this javascript (I forget where I stole it from some months or years ago):

```
function resizeScrollContainer() {
    var windowHeight;
    var newHeight;
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else {
        windowHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    };

    newHeight = windowHeight - document.getElementById("scrollContainer").scrollTop - 135;
    if (newHeight > 200) {
        document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.height = newHeight + "px";            
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.height = 200;
    }
}
window.onresize = resizeScrollContainer;
window.onload = resizeScrollContainer;
```

That javascript keeps the height of the main DIV just short of the height of the browser.  That takes care of the *height*.

I hope this helps!